# OpenERP Server Error - ImportError

Tags: odoo, server-error

I'm creating a company openERP system but when I tried to cancel an install pending in the "Update Modules" List, I consequently got this error popping up afterwards.

I can't even login anymore and get this error at the login-screen.

The problem is that I don't have any back-end access at the moment and it would take quite a while before it would be possible. Is there any chance I can fix this with another solution?

Below are the error codes I'm getting.

```
OpenERP Server Error
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 864, in authenticate
    req.session.authenticate(db, login, password, env)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/session.py", line 115, in authenticate
    uid = self.proxy('common').authenticate(db, login, password, env)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 433, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 444, in exp_authenticate
    res_users = pooler.get_pool(db).get('res.users')
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/pooler.py", line 49, in get_pool
    return get_db_and_pool(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)[1]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 203, in get
    update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 233, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 350, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 256, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 159, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 408, in load_openerp_module
    zimp.load_module(module_name)
  File "/opt/odoo/extra-addons/product_cost_incl_bom_price_history.zip/product_cost_incl_bom_price_history/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "/opt/odoo/extra-addons/product_cost_incl_bom_price_history.zip/product_cost_incl_bom_price_history/product.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 132, in load_module
    f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named product_price_history
```

The module Product Price History is the one I wanted to cancel the install. It's OpenErp v7.

Comment: check  ur addons folder for module whether it' been deleted or not

Comment: Hello, the problem is I don't have any server access at the moment. But I think getting it is the only way to solve this problem I suppose. If I could fix it without it I wouldn't lose that much time.